# Log4Net Instance in Two Different DLLs and Calling each Dll from a program - Issues

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have Two Dlls Both have their own instance of static logger like so:

```
public static  log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(logLabel);
```

I have a `Program.cs` File and Two Dlls  Named
1) `DllWXmlConfigurator` 
2) `DllWihtoutXmlConfigurator`.

This is the order I call the Dlls From the Program
1) `DllWihtoutXmlConfigurator  : do logging`

2) `DllWXmlConfigurator :do logging`   (this has `[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`)

Now no logging happens until I add

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Also to the DllWihtoutXmlConfigurator

I don't want to add this to the `program.cs` what I don't understand is why isn't each of these separate static instances and able to behave differently?

Why does the logging not happen until both of these have the line

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Picture View:
App_A has Two Dlls : Dll1 and Dll2

App_A-------->Dll1 has its own log4netRef and static logger

App_A-------->Dll2 That has its onw log4NetRef and static logger and the line   [assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

Application Starts and I call Dll1 for Logging Then I call Dll2 For logging ..no Logging Happens untill I add [assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]  to Dll1.

Comment: http://blog.falafel.com/using-log4net-with-multi-project-solutions/

Comment: I belive I found answer here but still does not clarify the core question how log4net takes over as globalinstance between two different projects in an app

Comment: unfortunately I am banned from answering my question :)